# Restricting access to static files in Python App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, authentication

I would like to restrict access to static *html and other files on google app engine.  The reason that I want to do this is because a considerable amount of my application is written in the javascript that is delivered with the HTML files and I only want authorized people to have access to this code.

I would also like to restrict access to HTTP resources that I have written using the webapp framework.  Ideally, I would like to write this authentication functionality myself.  Even more ideally, I'd like to use the same authentication to control access to static files.

I've been struggling with how to fulfill these requirements.  From what I can tell, the only way to restrict access to static files is by using the authentication provided by app engine: http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/auth.html  The problem with this solution is that it requires me to use whatever authentication scheme app engine has provided.  I already see problems with this because it requires a google account.  This requirement would not be appropriate for this application.

Another idea would be to restrict ALL access to static files and instead have the application read them and then send them through an HTTP resource that I have configured to require authentication.

I've very confused as to what a good solution would be.  Often, the answer to this type of question is what IS done in real-world applications.  Does anyone know what is done in real-world application of this nature?  Or does anyone have any ideas as to how I should handle this?

Thanks!

Comment: App Engine also provides authentication via OAuth instead of Google Accounts. I'd strongly caution against cooking up your own auth system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point of using static handlers is to be able to serve files without spinning up an instance of your Python app. If you need *custom* authentication logic to run first, static handlers won't work.

As for real-world applications, I think most people just accept that their Javascript and HTML aren't protectable. People don't want to steal your code as much as you think they do.

Comment: +1 for "people don't want to steal your code as much as you think they do". Even if they did, code that wasn't written with reusability in mind is a lot harder to repurpose than people think it is.

Comment: I'm definitely with you guys, unfortunately, the requirements aren't something that I have complete control over :(